# How do I persist custom subdomains in firebase hosting without redirects

Tags: subdomain, firebase-hosting

I've set up my custom domain with firebase hosting using their CNAME and A record details. Visiting http://sub.example.com redirects to https://example.com (not what I wanted)

I want to **persist** my subdomain (https://sub.example.com) **in the address bar** without the 301 redirect to (https://example.com) that I'm currently getting. Is this possible to set up this behavior within firebase hosting itself? I'd also like to point this sub domain to a certain html file/directory that I configure.

Comment: As far as I know, Firebase Hosting does not redirect unless you instruct it to do so in your [`firebase.json` configuration file](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#redirects).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen That's weird. My firebase.json file only has `{"hosting": {"public": "public"}}`

Comment: Firebase Hosting only allows one canonical domain for a site, and it's whatever you entered for add domain. You may need to remov e the domain and re-add as sub.mydomain.com

Comment: me too tried to do it but its not allowed in firebase, you cant point multiple subdomain on single firebase project, hence you will have to create separate projects for each subdomain in firebase.